# Edit json to csv output files

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq

I am trying to get `JSON` data by ‘curl’ and convert it to ‘`csv`’ with the ‘`jq`’ command.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
    #Remove previously generated output files 
    rm datacsv.csv  output.json 
   #Get crypto pairs data from the server (curl) in JSON from the COINAMRKET.COM server, save output.json 
              curl -H "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: 45f65521-ad1b-4dbb-9c33-743ba7a63e68" -H "Accept: application/json" -d "start=1&limit=50&convert=USD" -G https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest>output.json 
                             
     #Convert JSON to CSV, Outputfile: datacsv.csv                               
      jq -r '.data[]| [paths(scalars) | select( all(.[]; type=="string")) ] as $paths| ($paths |  map(["data"] + . | join("__"))),[ getpath($paths[]) ]|@tsv'  output.json  >datacsv.csv
```

Output `csv` file (`datacsv.csv`) has repeated header  for each record:

```
data__id    data__name  data__symbol    data__slug  data__num_market_pairs  data__date_added    data__max_supply    data__circulating_supply    data__total_supply  data__cmc_rank  data__last_updated  data__quote__USD__price data__quote__USD__volume_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_1h data__quote__USD__percent_change_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_7d data__quote__USD__percent_change_30d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_60d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_90d    data__quote__USD__market_cap    data__quote__USD__last_updated                  
1   Bitcoin BTC bitcoin 9547    2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z    21000000    18691931    18691931    1   2021-04-26T16:21:02.000Z    53285.1129054482    59530205038.6485    -0.6500853  5.53203621  -3.31916623 -3.33187743 4.07075949  69.03589533 996001653755.848    2021-04-26T16:21:02.000Z                    
data__id    data__name  data__symbol    data__slug  data__num_market_pairs  data__date_added    data__circulating_supply    data__total_supply  data__cmc_rank  data__last_updated  data__quote__USD__price data__quote__USD__volume_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_1h data__quote__USD__percent_change_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_7d data__quote__USD__percent_change_30d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_60d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_90d    data__quote__USD__market_cap    data__quote__USD__last_updated                      
1027    Ethereum    ETH ethereum    6312    2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z    115629413.749   115629413.749   2   2021-04-26T16:21:02.000Z    2482.06593555852    36892666790.3224    -0.23795873 5.43647682  16.16445289 46.51867774 51.11877441 94.25117671 286999829014.995    2021-04-26T16:21:02.000Z                        
1839    Binance Coin    BNB binance-coin    579 2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z    170532785   153432897   169432897   3   2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z    533.23090641431 4373867739.9739 0.03999376  3.29006408  8.84917842  103.69391599    108.02152044    1217.45571414   81815162741.0835    2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z                    
52  XRP XRP xrp 664 2013-08-04T00:00:00.000Z    100000000000    45404028640 99990831162 4   2021-04-26T16:21:03.000Z    1.24569103514058    13547433610.3615    0.9120132   9.79015802  -4.60461388 125.54110459    162.86485803    372.19710035    56559391436.1141    2021-04-26T16:21:03.000Z                    
data__id    data__name  data__symbol    data__slug  data__num_market_pairs  data__date_added    data__circulating_supply    data__total_supply  data__platform__id  data__platform__name    data__platform__symbol  data__platform__slug    data__platform__token_address   data__cmc_rank  data__last_updated  data__quote__USD__price data__quote__USD__volume_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_1h data__quote__USD__percent_change_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_7d data__quote__USD__percent_change_30d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_60d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_90d    data__quote__USD__market_cap    data__quote__USD__last_updated  
825 Tether  USDT    tether  12325   2015-02-25T00:00:00.000Z    50006254438.5217    51866290994.3298    1027    Ethereum    ETH ethereum    0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7  5   2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z    0.99997577777133    117822325986.94 -0.01985404 0.00891016  0.00656415  -0.1262222  -0.05070907 -0.14745816 50005043175.5917    2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z    
2010    Cardano ADA cardano 259 2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z    45000000000 31948309440.7478    45000000000 6   2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z    1.2163725547586 3494400505.85215    -0.63516459 6.44253956  1.77358151  2.5727442   8.69333792  266.42366354    38861046774.6607    2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z                    
74  Dogecoin    DOGE    dogecoin    331 2013-12-15T00:00:00.000Z    129348760639.944    129348760639.944    7   2021-04-26T16:21:03.000Z    0.26639640673017    6963087140.98019    -0.74842096 -1.96582346 -25.83236676    387.41281461    386.8290754 3173.67302946   34458045049.482 2021-04-26T16:21:03.000Z                        
6636    Polkadot    DOT polkadot-new    186 2020-08-19T00:00:00.000Z    932996847.726976    1068520962.58116    8   2021-04-26T16:21:06.000Z    32.3141434419601    2146407823.73721    -0.76428061 3.64699209  -7.2706416  0.41872077  -5.75544689 96.74696139 30148993968.3461    2021-04-26T16:21:06.000Z                        
data__id    data__name  data__symbol    data__slug  data__num_market_pairs  data__date_added    data__max_supply    data__circulating_supply    data__total_supply  data__platform__id  data__platform__name    data__platform__symbol  data__platform__slug    data__platform__token_address   data__cmc_rank  data__last_updated  data__quote__USD__price data__quote__USD__volume_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_1h data__quote__USD__percent_change_24h    data__quote__USD__percent_change_7d data__quote__USD__percent_change_30d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_60d    data__quote__USD__percent_change_90d    data__quote__USD__market_cap    data__quote__USD__last_updated
7083    Uniswap UNI uniswap 235 2020-09-17T00:00:00.000Z    1000000000  523384243.630469    1000000000  1027    Ethereum    ETH ethereum    0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984  9   2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z    35.2645393307245    1159198004.59251    -0.72129315 3.06863351  17.86724054 24.69707747 36.43669393 187.42707789    18456904244.5882    2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z
2   Litecoin    LTC litecoin    741 2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z    84000000    66752414.5153875    66752414.5153875    10  2021-04-26T16:21:02.000Z    241.772049644181    4873850130.55793    0.08569225  3.079198    -6.01020181 32.7958836  20.24742388 84.55115332 16138868076.0832    2021-04-26T16:21:02.000Z                    
1831    Bitcoin Cash    BCH bitcoin-cash    586 2017-07-23T00:00:00.000Z    21000000    18719506.25 18719506.25 11  2021-04-26T16:20:08.000Z    825.995177012163    4098896768.46408    -0.62457646 3.13607248  -8.10372907 65.63228051 51.71459366 96.05126285 15462221878.549 2021-04-26T16:20:08.000Z                    
1975    Chainlink   LINK    chainlink   495 2017-09-20T00:00:00.000Z    1000000000  419009556.434445    1000000000  1027    Ethereum    ETH ethereum    0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca  12  2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z    34.4665578984855    1711065668.01118    0.39416876  3.37393637  -5.31781365 29.84576669 22.2383717  55.53806504 14441817136.8665    2021-04-26T16:20:10.000Z
5426    Solana  SOL solana  41  2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z    269856622.936333    493886983.051495    13  2021-04-26T16:21:05.000Z    46.722213592056 1743822879.60336    -1.09733007 3.84673072  46.93695628 195.9965083 184.71221177    1146.97970713   12608298776.0623    2021-04-26T16:21:05.000Z
```

I want to filter output ‘csv’ file, get interested  fields (`data__id`,`data__name`,`data__symbol`,`data__slug`,`data__num_market_pairs`,`data__date_added`,`data__max_supply`,`data__circulating_supply`,`data__total_supply` )and exclude rest.

Desired output:

```
data__id    data__name  data__symbol    data__slug  data__num_market_pairs  data__date_added    data__max_supply    data__circulating_supply    data__total_supply
1   Bitcoin BTC bitcoin 9547    2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z    21000000    18691931    18691931
1027    Ethereum    ETH ethereum    6312    2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z    115629413.749   115629413.749   2
1839    Binance Coin    BNB binance-coin    579 2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z    170532785   153432897   169432897
52  XRP XRP xrp 664 2013-08-04T00:00:00.000Z    100000000000    45404028640 99990831162
825 Tether  USDT    tether  12325   2015-02-25T00:00:00.000Z    50006254438.5217    51866290994.3298    1027
2010    Cardano ADA cardano 259 2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z    45000000000 31948309440.7478    45000000000
74  Dogecoin    DOGE    dogecoin    331 2013-12-15T00:00:00.000Z    129348760639.944    129348760639.944    7
6636    Polkadot    DOT polkadot-new    186 2020-08-19T00:00:00.000Z    932996847.726976    1068520962.58116    8
7083    Uniswap UNI uniswap 235 2020-09-17T00:00:00.000Z    1000000000  523384243.630469    1000000000
2   Litecoin    LTC litecoin    741 2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z    84000000    66752414.5153875    66752414.5153875
1831    Bitcoin Cash    BCH bitcoin-cash    586 2017-07-23T00:00:00.000Z    21000000    18719506.25 18719506.25
1975    Chainlink   LINK    chainlink   495 2017-09-20T00:00:00.000Z    1000000000  419009556.434445    1000000000
5426    Solana  SOL solana  41  2020-04-10T00:00:00.000Z    269856622.936333    493886983.051495    13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emit the headers just once, you would use the template: `HEADERS, TABLE`:

```
def relevantPaths:
   "id,name,symbol,slug,num_market_pairs,date_added,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply"
  | split(",")
  | map([.]) ;

relevantPaths as $paths
| ([["data"] + $paths[]] | map(join("__"))),
  (.data[] | [ getpath($paths[]) ])
| @tsv
```

Comment: This works for the fields begin with "data__" 

like: 
"id,cmc_rank,name,symbol,slug,num_market_pairs,max_supply"

But it leaves empty fieleds begin with "data__platform" and "data__quote__USD" 

For example: 
data__platform__id, data__platform__name, data__platform__symbol, data__platform__slug

and 

data__quote__USD__percent_change_90d, data__quote__USD__market_cap, data__quote__USD__last_updated

Comment: @mehdishokati - SO is a Q&A website, not a free SE service. If your Q has been answered, it would be helpful if you accepted it and moved on from there. In this case, "moving on" could mean adapting the solutions that have been offered, or working with a SE to do so for you, or asking a new Q on SO in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and comments, I will add a new Q in SO.